# Printf spaces in front of pattern in C

Tags: c

my code is the following:

```
if (a == 4)
    {
        if (n >= 3 && n <= 18)
        {
            width = n + 2;

            for (a = 1; a <= width; a++)
            {
                printf("*");
            }
            printf("\n");
            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
                {
                    if (i == 1 || i == n || j == 1 || j == n)
                    {
                        printf("*");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf(" ");
                    }
                }
            printf("\n");
            }
        }
```

This code prints a pattern of lines depending on n.

e.g. For n = 7

```
*********
*******
*     *
*     *
*     *
*     *
*     *
*******
```

What I am trying to do is to print a space in front of every line like this

```
*********
 *******
 *     *
 *     *
 *     *
 *     *
 *     *
 *******
```

It should print the empty box in the middle of the upper line.

Comment: What part of your code is attempting to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `printf(" ");` between the 2 loops.

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    printf(" ");
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        ...
    }
    printf(" \n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this `code`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 7;
    if (n >= 3 && n <= 18)
    {
        int width = n + 2;
        for (int i = 0; i != width; ++i)
            printf("*");
        printf("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
        {
            printf(" ");
            for (int j = 0; j != n; ++j)
            {
                if (i == 0 || i == n - 1 || j == 0 || j == n - 1)
                    printf("*");
                else
                    printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```